# binding a CroppedBitmap to a bitmap image generate error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a CroppedBitmap on view which is bound to a property on videomodel.

The viewModel property is a bitmap like this:

```
public BitmapImage LogoImage
{
    get => logoImage;
    set
    {
        logoImage = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => LogoImage);
    }

 }
```

And my xaml code is like this:

```
<Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="318" Height="100" >
     <Image>
           <Image.Source>
                <CroppedBitmap Source="{Binding LogoImage}" SourceRect="20,20,50,50"/>
           </Image.Source>
     </Image>

</Viewbox>
```

When I run the application, I am getting an error that CroppedBitmap source is not set.

```
'Initialization of 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.CroppedBitmap' threw an exception.' Line number '90' and line position '48'.
'Source' property is not set.
```

I am sure that the LogoImage get proper data, as if I change the xaml code to this, it would work, but without cropping.

```
<Viewbox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="318" Height="100" >
  <Image Source="{Binding LogoImage}"   >
  </Image>
</Viewbox>
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: `Source="{Binding LogoImageFile}"` should perhaps be `Source="{Binding LogoImage}"`

Comment: @Clemens Thanks, It was a type error from when I copied the code from my source code to here. The original code is using LogoImage

Comment: Make sure that LogoImage has a valid value before InitializeComponent of the view is called.

Comment: @Clemens How can I do this? The view and ViewModel are separate classes and I have no control over how they are created.